# How do we pass user defined variable in controller to blade in Laravel

Tags: laravel

This is working perfectly but I want the return statement be in `<p>` tag on the view

**LARAVEL 8.x**

```php
$product = Product::find($id);

if(!$product) {
  abort(419);
}
    
$value = $request->session()->get('id');
    
if ($value == $id) {
  return "You can purchase an item at a time!";
} else {
  $initial = $product->quantity;

  if ($initial > 0)  {
    $final = $initial - 1;

    $product->quantity = $final; 
    $product->save();

    $request->session()->put('id', $id);

    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($product->quantity); 
  } else {
    return  "out of stock";
  }   
}
            
return redirect()->action([ProductController::class, 'index']);
```

I have tried how to do that. Though I could use `@if` on blade for the `$product->quantity` to display the "out of stock" but "you can only purchase an item at a time".

Comment: maybe you should use `return redirect()->action([ProductController::class, 'index'])->with(['[VARIABLE NAME], => [YOUR VARIABLE]'])` or if you configure a web route name do like this `return redirect()->route('products.index', '[YOUR VARIABLE HERE]')`

Comment: Where you get the error?

Comment: How do I consume it from the blade @codeformoney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it

**THE CONTROLLER YOU PROVIDED**

```php
$product = Product::find($id);

if(!$product) {
  abort(419);
}
    
$value = $request->session()->get('id');
    
if ($value == $id) {
  return "You can purchase an item at a time!";
} else {
  $initial = $product->quantity;

  if ($initial > 0)  {
    $final = $initial - 1;

    $product->quantity = $final; 
    $product->save();

    $request->session()->put('id', $id);

    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($product->quantity); 
  } else {
    return  "out of stock";
  }   
}
            
return redirect()->route('products.index')->with(['product' => $product]);
```

In your `web route` file you shoud have like this.

```php
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index'])->name('product.index');
```

Then in you blade component you can

```html
<h1> {{ $product->id ?? 'No Product ID given' }} </h1>
```